# Change the type of one of the objects property and sort it using LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, sorting

I want to sort the List where the objects properties are of string type.
One of the property is a time of string type, and when i try to sort it sorts like below.

```
1:12, 13:24, 19:56, 2:15, 26:34, 8:42.
```

Here the sorting is happening on string basis.
Now i want to convert that sting to double (1.12, 13.24, 19.56, 2.15, 26.34, 8.42) and sort it. Then populate the data by replacing the '.' with ':'.

I tried some thing like below, but still the sorting is happening on string basis.

```
public class Model
{
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    public string Dose { get; set; }
}

List<Model> lsModelData = new List<Model>();

//Added some model objects here

// query for sorting the lsModelData by time.
var sortedList = lsModelData.OrderBy(a => Convert.ToDouble(a.Duration.Replace(":", ".")));
```

I am trying to replace the time ":" with "." and then convert that to double to perform the sort operation.

Can any one please correct this statement to work this sorting properly.

Comment: Why don't just use one DateTime field in the Model class?

Comment: HI Joan, I updated my post. Its not exactly the date and time, just to make the properties general i used them. Sorry for creating confusion. I have a string property where it has to be sorted by converting them into a double.

Comment: I just double checked and your code works properly. First you replace the ":" with ".". Then you parse it to a double, and then you OrderBy that double value. Afterwards you will receive the original Model classes, and their Duration property will still have the ":", since you are not replacing it anywhere.

If you want to replace the Duration as well, replace your OrderBy with: `.Select(m => m.Duration = m.Duration.Replace(":", ".")).OrderBy(m => double.Parse(m.Duration))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort data according to duration try this. its tested surely works for you.

```
 public class Models
     {
         public string Duration { get; set; }
         public string Dose { get; set; }
     }



List<Models> lstModels = new List<Models>();    
lstModels.Add(new Models { Duration = "101:12" });
lstModels.Add(new Models { Duration = "13:24" });
lstModels.Add(new Models { Duration = "19:56" });                       
List<Models> sortedList = (from models in lstModels
                             select new Models
                               {
                                 Dose = models.Dose,
                                 Duration = models.Duration.Replace(':','.')})
                          .ToList()
                          .OrderBy(x=>Convert.ToDouble(x.Duration))
                          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really want, but if you want to return only the duration, then select it after sort

```
var sortedList = lsModelData.OrderBy(a => Convert.ToDouble(a.Duration.Replace(":", "."))).Select(a=> a.Duration).ToList();
```

or

```
var sortedList = lsModelData..Select(a=> a.Duration).OrderBy(a => Convert.ToDouble(a.Replace(":", "."))).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Hiep Le, Thanks for your reply. I want the whole List<Model> object has to be returned in a sorted order. Sorting with respect to duration. however i will try with your solutions.

Comment: Hi Hiep Le, My original code is sorting on the basis of string type.

Comment: @sivaRapolu No, your original code actually creates doubles out of a string and then orders by them. I also think it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this it works best to order by length and then by content:

```
var sortedList = lsModelData.OrderBy(a => a.Duration.Length)
                            .ThenBy(a => a.Duration)
```

Converting database data before sorting (or filtering) always makes queries inefficient because indexes can't be used anymore.